# How to list all connected nodes in android application (using WIFI)?

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, wireless, android-wireless

It is possible to list all connected nodes in my android application(machines connected to a LAN using wifi)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by following code,

this code is useful in java so not sure but 
it will work for android also.

public void getAllNodes(String subnet)
{

int pingTime=1000;
         String nodeName = "";
         for (int i=1;i<254;i++)
      {
            String host=subnet + "." + i;
                   if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(pingTime))
                  {
                            nodeName += host;
                  }
         }
}

Just call this method like getAllNodes("192.168.0");

Answer (score 0):

Try This One...

This will help you

to get all kind of net connections...

```
 public boolean checkNet() 
 {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo netWifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (netWifi != null && netWifi.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo netMob = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (netMob != null && netMob.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo netActive = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netActive != null && netActive.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: I want to list all the nodes in the LAN.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure but you can achieve it by following code.